# Discrete Random Variables: Changes to expected value and variance

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Is it correct to assume that the Expected value and Variance of Discrete random variable Y is obtained from simply plugging in the dependents E(X) and Var(X)?

Let X be a random variable with $E(X) = 2$ and $Var(X) = 5$ and $Y = 4X + 3$

Would the Expected value of Y then be:

$$E(Y)  = 4(E(X)) + 3  = 4(2) + 3 = 11$$

Also, would the Variance on Y be:

$$Var(Y)  = 4(Var(X)) + 3  = 4(5) + 3 = 23$$

Comment: Note that $var(aX) = a^2 var(X)$, and $var(c) = 0$, where $c$ is a constant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is $E(c)$ not equal to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Expected value is correct but
$$
Var(4X+3)  = Var(4X) = 16Var(X) = 16\times 5=80.
$$